# iCloud container changes with release of iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, containers, icloud, provisioning-profile

Since the release of iOS 8 on the 17th, all my development and deployment profiles are showing as invalid in the Apple dev center.  Also none of my apps using iCloud will run in either Xcode 5.1 or 6 GM on an actual device.  Get a message stating entitlements do not match provisioning profile.  The only acceptable iCloud containers now have to start with iCloud which do not recognize data already stored in iCloud using the previously require iCloud container naming structure.

Any solutions?  I've searched the web and Apple dev site for hours with no solutions found.  I can't be the only one having this problem.  Very frustrating after just releasing an App on the App Store and now can't change any code to update it!

Comment: I have a similar problem, I can't even build my project at the moment because the entitlements are wrong apparently (None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified capabilities: Features: iCloud. iCloud containers:)

Comment: I am still looking for a solution.  Nothing has worked yet.

Comment: Mine was solved by selecting "Use the default container" in the iCloud capability.

Comment: I can select old type container (which corresponds to $(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)) in the list of containers provided by XCode, but seems like update to iOS 8 itself brakes something and I see only endless error messages of CoreData+iCloud  trying to do something with already existing store. Once I deleted the app and reinstalled iOS7 version from store - everything started working as it supposed - data from cloud came to the app's database.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on `Use Default Container`
2. Click on `Specify Custom Containers`
3. Reselect your custom containers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the final answer, but I finally found a way to access the old iCloud information in my app on a device.  I returned to Xcode 5.1.1, deleted the entitlements file in my project.  Edited both the Development and Distribution profiles on iTunesConnect (using iCloud.xxxx settings that are only allowed now), downloaded and installed in Xcode 5.1.1.  I checked the Key-Value Store: under iCloud capabilities and clicked the + under Ubiquity Containers and made sure the targets all had the same container (com.companyName.AppName) for each target in the app.  Then attached an iOS device and ran the app.  Errors appeared, returned to each target and clicked "fix" under Capabilities - iCloud.  Had to click fix several times until no longer appeared.  Then ran the app again, the previous iCloud data stored in the app before iOS 8 release showed up in the app and all appears to work.

The above resulted in a separate entitlements file for each target, previously there was only one entitlements file used by all targets.

I have not tried with with Xcode 6 again yet, but I finally have access to my app through Xcode 5.1.1 and can work the fixes and enhancements for my published app again.

Update (11/5/2014): Was able to upload to app store for beta testing without problems using Xcode 5 with the above method.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I did this, but the old iCloud documents do not appear anymore.  I'm afraid that if I submit an update with the new iCloud container naming scheme (iCloud.xxx) my users lose all their data.  What am I missing?

Comment: Were you able to successfully build your app with XCode 6.x?